# Stored procedure for date time

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Hi I have written Stored Procedure like this

```
set @sSql =  'SELECT [Datetime] as Busidate,storenum,TransactionID,TransType, Cardnumber,Amount FROM [dts_SBTransInfo]inner join storeno st on st.number = dts_sbtransinfo.storenum WHERE  ErrorCode <> ''9009'' and isnull(void,0) = 0 
and  [Datetime] between   convert(varchar(10),''' + @sStartDate + ''', 112) and  convert(varchar(10),''' + @sEndDate + ''', 112)'
```

I am getting Output but without time. My Datetime field has date and time.

Comment: whats datatype of Datetime in table ?

Comment: The datatype of Datetime is datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Style 112 only provide date without time, if you want time you need to use other style, or alternatively use a combination of 112 an 108, such as:

`CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 108)`

Answer (score 0):

here is with style 100 it gives you date and time as

[image: With Datetime]

You can use this :

```
set @sSql =  'SELECT [Datetime] as Busidate,storenum,
TransactionID,TransType, Cardnumber,Amount 
FROM [dts_SBTransInfo]inner join storeno st 
on st.number = dts_sbtransinfo.storenum 
WHERE  ErrorCode <> ''9009'' and isnull(void,0) = 0 
and  [Datetime] between   convert(varchar(10),''' + @sStartDate + ''', 100) 
and  convert(varchar(10),''' + @sEndDate + ''', 100)'
```